# INT_SIZE_LENGTH for itow() is 20, why?

Tags: c, visual-c++

In my old Visual Studio 6 I found that calling itow(), which looks basically like this:

```
#define INT_SIZE_LENGTH 20

wchar_t* _itow(wchar_t*bif, int i, int radix)
{
   char abuf[INT_SIZE_LENGTH];
   itoa(abuf, i, radix);
   // convert_to_wide_char();
}
```

Now, notice the define `INT_SIZE_LENGTH`. Why is this set to 20?

Worst case for an int32 should be `-4294967295`, right. And that is only 11 characters, plus \0. (My own buffer, in the call to _itow, is only 13 long. I thought that was sufficient.)

(An positive int64 would be up to 20 characters, a negative up to 21. But this is the method for 32-bit integers.)

I feel like I am missing something here? Any ideas gratefully received.

(I looked at the code from Visual Studio 2008, and there the code was completely rewritten. So I guess the VS6 code is not that good.)

Comment: 20 is definitely *not enough* because `radix` could be 2.

Comment: At least the VC8 documentation says that `radix` *"must be in the range 2–36"*.

Comment: Well, I guess I knew that VC6 was buggy...

Comment: Shouldn't `abuf` be an array of `wchar_t`?

Comment: @tom: No, it is used with `itoa()` which takes a `char*`. The ommited part would then convert the `char` buffer to the `wchar_t` buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because it can emit non-decimal numbers, if `radix` is less than 10. Then the number of digits grows. On the other hand, that would imply that `INT_SIZE_LENGTH` should be 33, to support binary output.

Answer (score 1):

MSVC is buggy; big surprise. A correct length (for arbitrary base support) would be `sizeof(inttype)*CHAR_BIT/log2(minbase)+2`, where `minbase` is the minimum base you need to support. Round the logarithm down, of course.